# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: UserModel.find is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose

My `models/User.js` is like the following:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');    
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

class User {
    constructor() {
        this.user = mongoose.model('user', {
        ... ...
        }
    }       
}
const user = new User();
module.exports = user;
```

In `try/try.js`:

```
const UserModel = require('../models/Users')
... ...
let users = await UserModel.find({});
```

Then, running `node try.js` returns an error `(node:41525) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: UserModel.find is not a function`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code, you need to access the `user` property inside the instance of `User` class to use mongoose methods. It should be:

```
let users = await UserModel.user.find({});
```

*Note*: If you don't have any special reason/requirement to wrap the mongoose model inside a class, you can export directly the mongoose model and then your code in `try.js` will work.